# What do you call classes that do arbitrary work in your project?

Tags: naming, coding-standards, organization, naming-standards

I work on a lot of projects with different teams. Every project has its own conventions, including what to call arbitrary classes that don't lend themselves to obvious names.

As a counter-example, it's usually pretty obvious what you should name your models (UserModel, AlbumModel, etc.). The same goes for repositories, installers, controllers and views.

But inevitably there are classes that aren't as clear-cut. For example, I'm working on a project right now that has a ForumService that does the following:

1. Connect to the forum database and start a forum session
2. Retrieve forum posts and comments
3. Create posts and comments

At first, the name ForumService made sense. But then I read more about service-oriented programming and realized that many developers may consider a service to be something different entirely (like a web service). So now I'm considering whether I should call it ForumProvider or just Forum.

The team I work with full-time likes to name classes like this "Tasks" (e.g. AuthenticationTasks, UserTasks). We also have a lot of "Helpers" (e.g. ViewHelpers) and "Utilities" (e.g. HtmlUtilities) for smaller classes. Some developers don't like these ambiguous names just because they're ambiguous.

What do you normally use and why? Do most people generally prefer to avoid names like "Helpers" and "Utilities", and is there a good reason?

Comment: They are a code smell. Notice that you listed three things that the ForumService does. It sounds like the reason it has an ambiguous name is that the class does more than a single thing and so the class itself is ambiguous. If the responsibilities were more clearly encapsulated then you would not have this issue. It's sounds like you need ForumSession, ForumRepository, and ForumFactory classes instead.

Comment: I think he's just asking for a naming convention.  Usually if I add anything to the name its just 'Class'.  So the class would be called 'Forum' or 'ForumClass', depending on the language begin used.

Comment: @RibaldEddie a great point! I hadn't thought of that.

Comment: A forum session is a `session`. A post or a comment could be objects (resources) and sub-objects from the RESTful school of thinking. However, it is apparent that your team has chosen the names based on their psychological needs: they are in severe need of something *affectionate, cuddly, helpful and supportive*. Something that is apparently unfulfilled in the current work environment. From this perspective, `YogiBear` appears to be a legit choice.

Comment: @rwong "affectionate, cuddly, helpful and supportive" - what????

Comment: If your `ForumService` is basically doing CRUD operations on forum posts, then it looks more like a repository (although it doesn't communicate with a typical database, but that shouldn't matter in the naming).

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau it primarily calls methods on the forum's public API.

Comment: @GrandmasterB `Forum` sounds like a sound name for a class representing a forum, but `ForumClass`? It's clear that we're dealing with a class so putting that in a name sounds rather redundant and unnecessarily distracting.

Comment: @MichałKosmulski Which is why I said it depends on the language.  There is no language tag on the question.  It would not be uncommon to have a file full of functions in a Pascal file, for example.  In Java it'd be superfluous, but in other languages not so much.

Comment: @GrandmasterB Good point. I'd guess it also depends quite a lot on how advanced the IDEs for each particular language are.

Comment: @Koveras: Does it matter to the users of `ForumService` that it accesses the forum's public API and not the underlying database? If not, and if the API gives you the possibility to create, retrieve, update and/or delete forum posts, then you are performing basic CRUD operations on the forum. It is nowhere stated that a repository class can only use SQL to communicate with the underlying storage.

Answer (score 6):

Naming things can be tricky - A good rule of thumb is that if you are having trouble naming a class/function clearly then you should read it as a red-flag that you haven't thought about the architecture or design enough yet and should probably stop coding until you have.

For naming stick to the name of the object/concept being modelled and exclude the design patterns / non-object names for classes unless there is a specific reason to include them.  Some examples are...

- the class is purely or primarily implementing that pattern like `SomethingFactory`.
- a distinction is needed to avoid ambiguity like `StringBuilder`.
- the architecture (mvvm/mvc/mvp etc) uses it as a convention like `DisplayPostViewModel`.

In the case of your class it sounds like you're best off using something like `Forum` since that is the concept you're modelling.  You'd then need classes for the various objects it needs `Post` and `Template` for example.  You may want a `ForumFactory` to create the forum object and create a `Dal` object for it.